# Draggable DIV (with gridster.js) and inline editing not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, draggable, gridster

I want to build a draggable grid with [gridster](http://gridster.net/) and want to enable `contenteditable = true` in every draggable DIV. But at the moment I'm just able to drag the DIVs around, it seems that gridster.js is overruling the click event or something, so the `contenteditable = true` parameter does not recognize that I click into the DIV.

I tried to define a draggable handle, so that the DIV can be just dragged with that handle (this worked with jQuery UI draggable), but this also does not work.

Is it possible to drag the DIVs around, and when the user fires a double-click, the DIV where he clicked gets editable?

My HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="gridster">
    <ul>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
            <div contenteditable="true">Test 1</div>
            <span class="drag-handle">HAND</span>
        </li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
            <div contenteditable="true">Test 2</div>
            <span class="drag-handle">HAND</span>
        </li>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">
            <div contenteditable="true">Test 3</div>
            <span class="drag-handle">HAND</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My js looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var grid = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
        max_cols: 2,
        widget_margins: [10, 2],
        widget_base_dimensions: [140, 40],
        resize: {
            enabled: true,
            axes: ['x']
        },
        draggable: {
            handle: '.drag-handle'
        }
    })

    $("li").dblclick(function() {
        grid.data('gridster').disable();
        $(this + " p").attr("contenteditable","true");
    });
});
```

At the moment it works that after a double-click the gridster.js will get disabled, but the content is not editable afterwards.

**EDIT:** Seems that there is a problem with the `focus()` event. When I explicitly register the `click()` event and call a `focus()` on the editable element, I'm able to edit the text!

Comment: Do you have a problem with not being able to change caret position with mouse? Caret is always at the beginning of editable text, I can only move it using arrow keys. If you don't have this problem, could you post JFiddle with your working piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Gridster.js drag and resize handlers are intercepting `selectstart` event and canceling further propagation by returning false unless they are *both* disabled. To archive that call `gridster.disable(); gridster.disable_resize();` and enable them afterwards